# Bottom-sheet overlay UI element in React Native

Tags: react-native, user-interface, overlay, bottom-sheet

In some app in iOS I came accross a type of view that is `overlay another view`, and `come from bottom of the screen`. When the overlay view showing up, the view in the back is minimized. For example:

[image]
[image][image]

I want to implement this UI element in `react-native` but cannot find a good solution. What I have achived sofar is `bottom-sheet`.

So the question is does this type of UI element can be implemented using react-native? If yes, could you please provide some suggestion/library to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Actually this is not a overlay view it is a native modal screen on iOS. This feature is given by the navigation library. If you are using wix/react-native-navigation you can open this kind of modal using Navigation.openModal() function and if you are using react-navigation then you need to use react-native-screens to get the native look and feel of modal and register the component as a modal component using some configuration.
For Example:

```
<NativeStack.Screen
      name="Third"
      component={Second}
      options={{
        title: 'MODAL',
        stackPresentation: 'fullScreenModal',
        headerBackTitle: 'back',
        headerCenter: () => <Text>MODAL!!</Text>,
        headerHideBackButton: false,
        headerLeft: () => <Button title="Button" />,
        headerLargeTitle: true,
        headerShown: true,
        headerRight: () => <Button title="Back" onPress={() => null} />,
      }}
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. It's actually modal (presentation `modal`) with [transition presets](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator#transitionpresets) in screenOptions. This is how we can achieve this with `react-navigation`:

```
<AppStack.Navigator
    initialRouteName="Main"
    screenOptions={{
        headerShown: false,
        gestureEnabled: true,
         cardOverlayEnabled: true,
         ...TransitionPresets.ModalPresentationIOS
    }}
     headerMode='none'
     presentation="modal"
>
    <AppStack.Screen name="Main" component={Main} />
</AppStack.Navigator>
```